# Keras/Tensorflow calculate mean_iou for batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, metrics

I'm trying to calculate the `mean_iou` and update a confusion matrix for each batch. But after 30 steps I get a SIGKILL event. The images which I use in my generator have the resolution of 2048x1024 because of this my batch_size is 2. It seems that I can't release the memory after one step is finished. I tested the generator while I'm iterating over all images but everything works well.

I'm using Keras 2.1.2 with Tensorflow 1.4.1 as Backend on a GTX 1080. It would be really nice if someone have an advice.

```
def calculate_iou_tf(model, generator, steps, num_classes):
    conf_m = K.tf.zeros((num_classes, num_classes), dtype=K.tf.float64)
    generator.reset()
    pb = Progbar(steps)
    for i in range(0, steps):
        x, y_true = generator.next()
        y_pred = model.predict_on_batch(x)

        # num_classes = K.int_shape(y_pred)[-1]
        y_pred = K.flatten(K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1))
        y_true = K.reshape(y_true, (-1,))

        mask = K.less_equal(y_true, num_classes - 1)
        y_true = K.tf.to_int32(K.tf.boolean_mask(y_true, mask))
        y_pred = K.tf.to_int32(K.tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask))

        mIoU, up_op = K.tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_iou(y_pred, y_true, num_classes, updates_collections=[conf_m])
        K.get_session().run(K.tf.local_variables_initializer())
        with K.tf.control_dependencies([up_op]):
            score = K.eval(mIoU)
            print(score)

        pb.update(i + 1)

    conf_m = K.eval(conf_m)
    return conf_m, K.eval(mIoU)
```

Comment: Why are you using `K` function instead of `numpy`?

Comment: I'm using Tensorflow (K is just the Keras Backend) for a calculation on the GPU

Comment: But every time you define the tensor - it's allocated and unfortunately not released with current `tensorflow` implementation. Moreover - I don't expect a much of speed up from pushing computations to `gpu`.

Comment: Ok what a pity but thanks for your help! The CPU version is running without problems.

Comment: So may I formulate an answer?

Comment: Yes please and again thanks for your help!

Comment: If @MarcinMożejko's answer solved your problem then please Accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lied in using `keras.backend` functions instead of `numpy` ones. Every time when a function was called - a new tensor was created. Unfortunately - with the current implementation of `tf` - there is no a systematic garbage collection of tensors - so this made memory full error. Switching to `numpy` solved the problem.